# squid3 https_port requires --enable-ssl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, squid

Using squid3 -k parse I see this:

Processing: https_port 443 cert=myCA.pem
ERROR: 'https_port' requires --enable-ssl

How to enable ssl?

Output of 
`squid3 -v`

> Squid Cache: Version 3.4.8 linux configure options:
>   '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr'
>   '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man'
>   '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc'
>   '--localstatedir=/var' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/squid3'
>   '--srcdir=.' '--disable-maintainer-mode'
>   '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-silent-rules'
>   '--datadir=/usr/share/squid3' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid3'
>   '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--enable-inline' '--disable-arch-native'
>   '--enable-async-io=8' '--enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock'
>   '--enable-removal-policies=lru,heap' '--enable-delay-pools'
>   '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-icap-client'
>   '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for'
>   '--enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,LDAP,MSNT,MSNT-multi-domain,NCSA,NIS,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB'
>   '--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP'
>   '--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper'
>   '--enable-auth-ntlm=fake,smb_lm'
>   '--enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,kerberos_ldap_group,LDAP_group,session,SQL_session,unix_group,wbinfo_group'
>   '--enable-url-rewrite-helpers=fake' '--enable-eui' '--enable-esi'
>   '--enable-icmp' '--enable-zph-qos' '--enable-ecap'
>   '--disable-translation' '--with-swapdir=/var/spool/squid3'
>   '--with-logdir=/var/log/squid3' '--with-pidfile=/var/run/squid3.pid'
>   '--with-filedescriptors=65536' '--with-large-files'
>   '--with-default-user=proxy' '--enable-build-info= linux'
>   '--enable-linux-netfilter' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g
>   -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall' 'LDFLAGS=-fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIE
>   -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'

Comment: Which version? Which debian? Which....you get the drill. But there is a "bug" in squid3 for debian repos: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid3/+bug/16669 actually it just was disabled. Depends on your version...

Comment: squid Version 3.4.8.  debian 8.5

Comment: Add the output of `squid3 -v`

Comment: I put data in Answer

Comment: @yunqian, please put that in your original question (you can edit your post) and not as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as shown in your `squid3 -v` output, you don't have the `--enable-ssl` flag in your squid compiled options. So no SSL for you, I'm afraid. Compile it with the `--enable-ssl` flag or use different methods, like [SslBump](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/BumpSslServerFirst).